# How to group and sum a result of a query sums

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, oracle-sqldeveloper

The title is slightly confusing but I am not sure how to phrase the question. Here are some more details:

I have written a query that gives me results such as these:

[image: Sample Query needing to be grouped. (6 records)]

This is the correct result and I do not want to change this query. What I want to accomplish is to only have two results with the same name, keeping the earliest date and grouping the rest.

I have tried:

```
select name, SUM(sum) as sum, edate
FROM
(--MY QUERY RESULT--)
group by name, date having edate > '15-Apr-02';
```

I have also tried using case based on if the record edate is null but I want this to always return two records per name (1 with the earliest edate and group all the others to the next earliest edate)

The result I am looking for with the super simple query above:

[image: Sample Result Query. (4 Records)]

Any help/ideas would be fantastic!

Comment: We need to see your query here, in your post. There's no need to use an image; you can use plain text to show both your sample data, your SQL statement, and the output you'd like to get as a final result. Images should be used only to illustrate things that can't be explained in text - [here's a list of reasons why](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576). Can you [edit] your post to do that instead? It would help if while you're editing you provided a tag for the specific DBMS you're using as well; syntax and functionality are different between various database engines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
WITH CTETab (NAME, EDATE)
AS
(
    --SELECT The earliest EDATE for each NAME
    SELECT
        NAME
        , MIN(EDATE) AS EDATE
    FROM
        @Tab
    GROUP BY NAME
)
SELECT
    T.NAME, [COUNT], T.EDATE
FROM
    @Tab AS T
    INNER JOIN
    CTETab AS CT
        ON T.NAME = CT.NAME
            AND T.EDATE = CT.EDATE
UNION ALL
SELECT
    T.NAME, SUM([COUNT]), MAX(T.EDATE)
FROM
    @Tab AS T
    INNER JOIN
    CTETab AS CT
        ON T.NAME = CT.NAME
            AND (T.EDATE <> CT.EDATE OR T.EDATE IS NULL)
GROUP BY T.NAME
ORDER BY T.NAME, T.EDATE
```

It works in SQL Server 2012 (2014, 2016).

You can change WITH clause by Subquery and use it for each SELECT statement.